# MySQL Fulltext Search. Get all records

Tags: mysql

In a FTS condition, How would i do something similar like this:

`SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_first_name LIKE "%" OR student_last_name LIKE "%" ...`

My current query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT cs.student_id,
          cs.class_id,
          s.student_id_no,
          s.student_image,
          s.student_first_name,
          s.student_middle_name,
          s.student_last_name,
          s.student_year,
          s.student_section,
          s.student_email_address,
          s.student_contact_no
   FROM `class_students` cs
   JOIN classes cls ON cs.class_id = cls.class_id
   JOIN students s ON cs.student_id = s.student_id
   WHERE cls.class_id = 1
     AND cls.teacher_id = 1
     AND is_enrolled = 1) AS s
WHERE MATCH(s.student_id_no, s.student_first_name, s.student_middle_name, s.student_last_name, s.student_email_address, s.student_contact_no) AGAINST ('*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but it gives me an error.

`#1064 - syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'`

I tried to remove the `IN BOOLEAN MODE`, it works but no records is retrieved.

I want to retrieve all the records if the search text is empty.

the `*` in the `AGAINST` clause will be concatinated with the search string.

e.g. `AGAINST('mysearch*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. I'm using PDO by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use '%' or '*' to indicate "no criteria selected".  Instead modify the query to remove the `WHERE...`.  Yes, this will require application code, but it will avoid your problem and speed things up.

Comment: What i meant was, If the search text passed is empty, I want to display all the records. In a `LIKE` condition, `WHERE field LIKE '%'` will retrieve all the records. If the search text is not empty, then it will be `WHERE field LIKE 'searchText%'` and retrieves relevant records. How can i do something similar with the `FULLTEXT SEARCH` condition `MATCH...AGAINST` ?

Comment: Yes, but it is `... AGAINST('term*' ...)`, but I don't think you can have simply `'*'`, hence the need to write code.

Comment: So it is not possible? :(